# How do I fix an empty organization list in the Fabric Unity plugin during preparation?

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-fabric

Backstory:  I have had an existing Fabric account, with access to a previous team's title.  Said title was built in C++ for Android and for iOS natively, not Unity.  I've since moved to a new title, at a new studio, under the same parent organization - so I've kept my email address, etc.

I've been tasked with investigating Crashlytics integration into my current title (built in Unity), since I had prior experience at my old studio.  I'm following the documentation at https://docs.fabric.io/unity/crashlytics/installation.html.  I've downloaded the Fabric plugin, and included it in our existing project.  However, when I attempted to "Prepare Fabric", the resulting window ("Please select your organization") initially had no results.  I then created a new organization, at which point that window had two button options, one for the old studio and one for the new.

Neither button seemed to have any functionality when clicked.  Working under the assumption that I was getting some pollution from my old organization, I removed myself from it (so I am ostensibly only in my new organization, and in fact am both an admin and the only current member).  That just returned the selection window to the point of having no options again.

Trying to access the Fabric dashboard just gets me an onboarding screen, with no access to either the dashboard or my organization.  From there, I can begin the package download process again, but can go no further.  The standard 'gear' icon I'm used to seeing for user account settings is now just a power-button icon which I can use to log off.  (Logging off and back on does not fix the problem, though).

What step(s) am I missing?  Is my account borked due to membership in a prior organization?  How do I get back on track?

Thanks!

Comment: Mike from Fabric here. You may want to email support(at)fabric(dot)io on this issue, but knowing your Fabric account email address would be the first step in digging in on this.

Comment: Thanks!  Mailing now, and will include the Fabric account info in that mail.

Answer (score 1):

After taking this offline, Mike from Fabric was able to help me figure this out.  Ultimately the problem boiled down to the fact that I was attempting to include the Fabric plugin at a different location in our project.  Moving the plugin to a home directly under the root /Assets folder fixed all the issues, and I'm now unblocked moving forward.

Thanks again, Mike!